# Including file from main domain on subdomain

Tags: php

I used to include files between sites routinely, until my webhost banned the practice. Now it appears that a recent PHP upgrade also tightened the screws, as I'm getting a "no suitable wrapper could be found" error - and I'm working with LOCAL sites.

Let's start with a website @ www.gx.com and a subdomain at subdomain.mysite.com. However, they display locally as two separate websites - mysite.com and subdomain.com.

A page on subdomain.com features the following include request:

```
require_once($GX_URL."/2b/inc/D/Shared/Body/Bottom/Footer.php
```

$GX_URL displays as http[://]gx locally and http[://]gx.com online.

How can I modify this include so it works in both situations? I can use the following switch to hold two separate includes, one for online use and the other for local use:

```
switch(PHP_OS)
{
 case 'Linux':
 break;
 default:
 break;
}
```

I just figured the answer to my first question; I simply mapped out the entire path to the file in the other website on my computer:
                                  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gx/2b/inc/D/Shared/Body/Bottom/Footer.php

So I guess I need to do something similar to include a file from my main domain. However, I'll leave this question open in case anyone has a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have more you can try one.

1. Try download html and include to your php page :).

   - Http Request or CURL request
2. Use **Allow_url_include**, example:  http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Allow_url_include
3. Use Object download: http://php.net/manual/de/function.ob-start.php

**Example::**

**1. Curl Download html string**

```
function curl_get($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->CURL_UA);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->YT_BASE_URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        return $contents;
    }
```

**2. Http send request width file_get_contents**

```
function sendRequest($url, $data = array())
    {
        $data = http_build_query($data);
        $context_options = array('http' => array('method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
            'content' => $data)
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($context_options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        return $result;
    }
```

**3 Object : http://php.net/manual/de/function.ob-start.php**